# Win10Pro -> local group policy ( No Domain ) -> Lock Windows Defender Settings ( Force Firewall & Antivirus to be enabled)

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I have a win10Pro 1709 OS. The computer is NOT connected to a Domain.

There is one user with user type "Administrator".

I want to configure Windows Defender ( Firewall & Antivirus) only with the local Computer Policy and disable the configuration through the local user interface "Control Panel".

This means that the possibility to disable the Windows Defender Firewall through the normal settings is disabled:

The Settings should be greyed out and a warning like "Some settings are managed by your organization" should appear:
[image]

I know that an administrator user can then use the gpedit.msc to change the settings, but he cannot use the "normal" settings app anymore.

I cannot find local Group Policy settings to do that.
The closest I can find is this:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus > Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus policy

I look for the opposite "force Windows Defender Antivirus/Firewall" to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1709 is out of date now.

Look here in Gpedit.msc (make sure you run this as Administrator)

Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus > Real Time Protection and make sure "Turn off Real Time protection" has been set to "Not Configured" and "No" under Comment

Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus  >  and make sure "Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus" has been set to "Not Configured"  and "No" under Comment.

Make sure no other Third Party Antivirus applications are running and then Windows Defender will be ON.

Many third party Antivirus applications turn Windows Defender OFF.